# Adding suggestions for arguments to the chemnum-package

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, texstudio, auto-completion, chemnum

I am writing my thesis in chemistry and use the `chemnum`-package to number my compounds. Because it is gotten quite a few compounds now, I would like to get suggestions from texstudio, which tags for compounds I already used, like it is the case for the `\ref`- or the `\cite`-command.

Because texstudio doesn't recognise the commands of `chemnum`, I made myself a `chemnum_user.cwl` file in `.\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\completion\user` with the content:

```
\initcmpd{tag}#n
\cmpd{tag}#n
\cmpd+{tag}#n
\replacecmpd{tag}#n
```

Is there a way, that texstudio shows me all the tags, that are used in one of the commands before, if I type `\cmpd{` ?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}    
\usepackage{chemnum}
\begin{document}

This is the first time, I call the chemical 1: \cmpd{chemical1}.

If I call it a second time, I would like texstudio, to suggest "chemical1" as argument of \verb|\cmpd{}|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any list of tags, that the chemnum package produces, that you could retrieve the used tags from? Propably this is the way, the \ref-command does it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You should define it with `#r` classifier (see [docs](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION)). Like:

```
\cmpd{tag}#r
```

I don't have TexStudio now, so can't check if it works.

Comment: This makes, that I get now the list of labels, I assigned to chapters, figures, etc. as suggestions for the argument. But this doesn´t help my case, because I need the tags, that were assigned to the compounds and written in the arguments of the \cmpd

Comment: With \initcmpd{cmpd%labeldef}#l and \cmpd{cmpd%ref}#r I get now the labels, that were defined with \initcmpd also suggested for \cmpd. But this doesnt solve the problem, that the command \cmpd also innitiates labels. All these labels are still not shown. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Ok, I understand. But from TexStudio manual, i see that there is no way with one command to define label and use it in the same time.